# Trouble displaying custom posts only if the date field is after today's date

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to display posts of a custom post type only if the 'Date' field is after today's date. The custom post type is 'Event', and the 'Date' field is in the format yyyy-mm-dd.
However when I use the following query all of my events are returned even though two of them are before today's date.

```
           <?php

                $today = date('Y-m-d');
                $args = array (
                    'post_type' => 'Event',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                         array(
                            'key'       => 'Date',
                            'compare'   => '>=',
                            'value'     => $today
                        )
                    ),
                );

                 $query = new WP_Query($args);  
                ?>
```

And if I use the date_query instead like the following then nothing is returned or displayed.

```
     <?php $today = date('Y-m-d');

            $args = array (
                'post_type' => 'Event',
                'date_query' => array(
                     array(
                        'key'       => 'Date',
                        'after'     => $today
                    ),
                    'inclusive' => true,
                ),
            );


             $query = new WP_Query($args);  ?>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, If it will not work then you need to match the date format

```
<?php

                $today = date('Y-m-d');
                $args = array (
                    'post_type' => 'Event',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                         array(
                            'key'       => 'Date',
                            'compare'   => '>=',
                            'value'     => $today,
                            'type' => 'DATE',
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                 $query = new WP_Query($args);  
                ?>
```

Comment: That didn't work, I think I'll need to match the date format then. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You can try this function                                                                                      $originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));

Answer (score 0):

you should use current_time() function to get todays date it will give you the time according to wordpress time format.